# cracks on both side of the bay window

Tags: foundation, structural

my house is a typical semi detached 1930 house, there are two cracks on the both side of the bay window
, they are roughly about 3-4cm wide, it was easy to filled it up with the mortar.

the crack is caused by the front wall slightly moving forward, or perhaps the rest of the house moving backwards while pulling the front wall to cause the crack.

most of the houses on the street have got the identical issue, after spoken to the neighbours no one seems worried about it!

when I first purchased the house, the home buyers report did mention it, but wasn't rated as a serious problem. and didn't explain the reason why the house has moved, or is it likely to get worst or not

my question is, is there any way to stop it getting worst? or anyone had the similar problem knows the more about 
the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If this is an actual bay window in a flat wall, then it's due to a very poor decision to put a bay window in brick or stone, the window is causing too much stress. Brick or stone is great at handling vertical loads, but quite poor at handling lateral loads. A flat window & some brick or stone re-laying & re-pointing will be the only remedy to this type of problem.

Now, if this is actually a whole bay wall that the window simply sits in. Then, that's alarming. Any separation of the bay wall from the building means it's very bad & needs **much more** than crack patching. You have a rotting foundation under that bay wall from almost a century of trapped moisture weakening the mortar & brick or stone. Unless, it can be determined that the house is collapsing backwards (i.e. multiple wall cracks inside & out), the problem is usually the bay wall tipping out & away from the bottom. The cracks should be wider at the top than at the bottom.

To remedy the bay wall scenario involves installing very beefy temporary supports, jacking the entire bay wall back into place & then re-building the bay wall's foundation. Only after all of that & 30-days mortar curing & effort evaluation do you then re-install & re-point the formerly detached bricks or stones.

Comment: yes the cracks are wider at the top (4cm)  and thinner at the bottom (1cm)

Comment: yes the cracks are wider at the top (4cm)  and thinner at the bottom (1cm), but those cracks are the only cracks inside and out, I even checked the loft and lifted the floor boards there are no cracks...... also after lifting the floor boards on the ground floor, fully expose the foundation, I can see it's very dry, and no signs of rotting  at all, all the timbers are in very good condition. The only problem obvious  is the gap between the foundation and  the front wall, the gap is only 2cm deep

Comment: That's not at all good. That's a very big gap. No water inside is the benefit of a vertical gap, since water will just ride the crack down. And, there may be no signs of anything in the basement either. Think of the wall's foundation as your foot. The wall used to be resting solidly on its heel, but now it's very weakly resting on just its toes. Get a Foundation Repair Company out very soon. Just a few more degrees of tilt-out could mean total collapse of the wall or complete fall away into & across the street.

Comment: after spoken to neighbours, the gap was there 20 years ago, and it haven't gone any worst ever since (everyone got the same condition), that's why they are not worried, perhaps that also why the home buyer's report didn't think its a serious problem. There are no trees grown around the house, the water drainage is good, we think its a shrink and swell problem on the soil the foundation sits on. and we have very little control over it. we will keep monitoring the condition, if it gets worst   the structure engineer has to use the hydraulic jack to lift the house up.

Comment: sorry Iggy i did upvote but can't choose it as the answer, because in lots of cases, a small problem which has been there for 20 years, doesn't need a immediate fix, and you didn't mention much about the potential cause of the problem, but more or less what you said is correct!

Comment: Oh well, I wouldn't want the place like that & I wouldn't buy it. I hope it doesn't bite you. How long it takes to collapse won't matter when it goes & it will go sooner or later.